# Position a button on top-right of the image for images of different aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I am trying to position the button on the top-right of the image.

Here is the fiddle with a small portion of the code that I am trying to implement : https://jsfiddle.net/sc5vfu9e/3/

```css
.modalDialog {
 position: fixed;
 font-family: "Proxima-Nova", sans-serif;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 z-index: 10;
  text-align: center;
}

.modalDialog > div {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.modalDialog img {
 max-width: 95%;
 max-height: 95%;
 position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.closeModal {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 50%;
 display: block;
 background: #606060;
 color: white;
 font-size: 0.5em;
 line-height: 25px;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 50%;
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 24px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000; 
}

.closeModal:hover,
.closeModal:active,
.closeModal:focus {
 background: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modalDialog">
      <div>
       <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/f2/c3/9c/f2c39c1651d11f47c5a5f35f205663fa.jpg" alt="Image" id="">
       <a href="#" title="close" class="closeModal">x</a>
      </div>
     </div>
```

**I will be loading images of different aspect ratios.** How can I have the close button on the top-right of the image in each case?

PS: I am new at programming, so please bear with any ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, try this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sc5vfu9e/5/)

**Updated** [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sc5vfu9e/10/)

```css
.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: "Proxima-Nova", sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 10;
  text-align: center;
}

.modalDialog > div {
  position: relative;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  margin: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div > div {
  width: auto;
  height: 95%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  img {
    max-height: 95%;
    width: auto;
  }
}

.closeModal {
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  /* adjust these accordingly*/
  top: -12px;
  /*adjust these accordingly */
  display: block;
  background: #606060;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 24px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.closeModal:hover,
.closeModal:active,
.closeModal:focus {
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="modalDialog">
  <div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/f2/c3/9c/f2c39c1651d11f47c5a5f35f205663fa.jpg" alt="Image" id="">
      <a href="#" title="close" class="closeModal">x</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this does not work at larger screen size: https://jsfiddle.net/sc5vfu9e/5/

Comment: Thanks, works, but shouldnt need to use media query for it. Anyways, someone helped me on facebook, I will post the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Someone helped me out on facebook. This solution uses viewport height instead of maximum width which does not work well when the height of the container is not defined.

https://jsfiddle.net/sc5vfu9e/8/

```
.modalDialog img {
display: inline-block;
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this.

Is this right what you need ?

```css
.modalDialog {
 position: fixed;
 font-family: "Proxima-Nova", sans-serif;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 z-index: 10;
  text-align: center;
}

.modalDialog > div {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.modalDialog img {
 max-width: 95%;
 max-height: 95%;
 position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.closeModal {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 50%;
 display: block;
 background: #606060;
 color: white;
 font-size: 0.5em;
 line-height: 25px;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 50%;
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 24px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000; 
}

.closeModal:hover,
.closeModal:active,
.closeModal:focus {
 background: #333;
}
.closeModal
{
  top:0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="modalDialog">
   <div>
<img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/f2/c3/9c/f2c39c1651d11f47c5a5f35f205663fa.jpg" alt="Image" id="">
<a href="#" title="close" class="closeModal">x</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need the button on top-right of the image and not top-right of the page.

Comment: @AmitSaxena ok i got your point. let me try and make some changes